# Passing an ArrayList between methods

Tags: java, arraylist

In my continuing education on Arrays and ArrayLists I'm trying to smarten up my code by passing an ArrayList from one method to another.  Here is my code:

```
public void exampleArrayList () {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    al.add("AZ");
    al.add("BY");
    al.add("CX");
    al.add("DW");
    al.add("EV");
    al.add("FU");
    al.add("GT");

    display(al);
}

public void display(ArrayList al) {

    System.out.println("Index of 'AZ': " + al.indexOf("AZ"));
    System.out.println("Index of 'FU': " + al.indexOf("FU"));
    System.out.println("Index of 'AA': " + al.indexOf("AA"));
    System.out.println("Index of 'CX': " + al.indexOf("CX"));

    // for (String row : al)
    //   System.out.println("Value at Index " + al.indexOf(row) +
    //      " is " + al.get(al.indexOf(row)));

    for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
        System.out.println("Value at Index " + al.indexOf(i) +
            " is " + al.get(al.indexOf(i)));
}
```

In the display method works with both for statements commented out.  The for statement that is currently commented out doesn't work because row is looking for a String but get's assigned an object even although array al is a string. Do I need to cast al into a string or something?  This is not the case when I run the for loop when the loop is in the same method that created the ArrayList in and I don't understand the difference.

The second for statement that isn't commented out causes a crash giving me the following runtime error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
```

I tried changing the `i < al.size()` to a hard coded number and it still failed and I don't know why.

Comment: I think you meant "value at index `i` is `al.get(i)`"?

Comment: Exactly right cricket.  Just got myself tied in knots thinking about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You need to pass it as an `ArrayList<String>`:

```
public void display(ArrayList<String> al) {
                             ^^^^^^^^
```

2) You're searching for the integers in the list. The list doesn't contain any integers, so `indexOf` returns -1. Then you call `al.get(-1)` where -1 is obviously out of bounds. I'm not sure what you meant to do here.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know. Passing it as a string.  Then I see my glaring error regarding the index because I had been mixing up two different pieces of code in my head.  Time to take a break I think.  Thanks for the help.  Slowly this stuff is beginning to make sense. Airfix.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-), which, given an `int`, will search for that `int` and return its index if the list contains it. As this isn't the case - it is a `List<String>` - you get index out of bounds because you are trying to retrieve an element at index -1. -1 is returned from `indexOf()` if the element can't be found, which it can't.

This is why you shouldn't use raw types. Use [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) and a `List<String>` as your parameter (no need to make it specifically `ArrayList`s):

```
System.out.println("Value at Index " + i +
    " is " + al.get(i));
```

and

```
public void display(ArrayList<String> al) {
```

Answer (score 1):

One other thing to "smarten the code" is to not use the specific implementation in the declaration or parameters.

```
public void exampleArrayList () {
   // use the interface List<T>, not the specific implementation ArrayList<T>
   List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

   ...
}

// take the Interface, and give it the type
public void display(List<String> al) {
  ....
}
```

The functionality will be the same, but it is a better programming approach to program to interfaces rather than implementations.

**EDIT**: Also, unless you really need the index for some reason, using the enhance for loop may be more appropriate

```
for (String s : al) {
  //some operation
}
```

Comment: If I understand the first comment ArrayList being an implementation of a List you're basically saying that I have more flexibility somehow by not calling the implementation (which I don't understand yet at my basic level of java knowledge). Regarding the enhanced loop, I came from basic knowledge of fortran, C and visual basic basic so this is my forst forte into oo programming and I'm still learning the ropes.  If in doubt I fall back on my roots.

Comment: @Airfix, [Programming to interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) has a number of benefits as that answer indicates. [Another take on it here](http://www.fatagnus.com/program-to-an-interface-not-an-implementation/). Generally, you want to preserve the ability to change the implementation if needed. Today you have an `ArrayList`, but perhaps tomorrow a `LinkedList` is more appropriate. If you have `List<T>` in the parameter, you may adjust the implementation, and the other code is unaware.